# Multiple residencies along with multiple citizenships

Tags: passports, dual-nationality, residency

Can a person have multiple residencies and each one in the country he/she is a citizen of? And can he/she have these residences printed each one in the respective country he/she is a citizen of? For example if one has a property/house in his/her name in every country he is citizen, is it internationally possible?
Example to clarify: Let's say I'm a citizen of Kuwait, Belgium and Morocco.
Is it legally possible to put, as residence, Rabat in Moroccan passport, Kuwait city in Kuwaiti passport and Bruxelles in Belgian passport IF I have three houses and each one in one of those cities. Can it create me troubles when it comes to travel?

Comment: Your question is not very clear and is not exactly about travel. It may have more to do with tax law etc. You can be a dual tax resident. You could also conceivably be a resident of two countries IF they don’t require you to spend at least half the year there.

Comment: Aren't taxes based on income? So I have to pay taxes just for owning something in a land, haven't I?

Comment: I'll clarify. Can I have a residency in every country whose I have a passport? If I own a house in country A and likewise in B and C, can I put that I live in A in passport A, in B in passport B and in C in passport C if I own a house in A, a house in B and a house in C????

Comment: The question of what residency you list in passport A depends on how residency is defined in the laws of country A.  The question of what residency you list in passport B depends on the laws of country B.  Those laws don't all have to be the same, nor even consistent with one another.  This question cannot be answered in general.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a little unclear, so let's try to answer what I believe you are asking, staring with "Can someone be a resident of more than one country?".

In principle to be a 'resident' of somewhere means that you live there, and in most cases it is assumed that you live in only one place. But that doesn't have to be the case legally.

Every country has their own definition of what it means to be a 'resident', (Each one may in fact have multiple definitions of 'resident' - one for tax, one for healthcare, one for legal immigration status etc.) By using these definitions carefully it is possible to  be resident in more than one country, or to be resident in none. For example if two countries define 'resident' as someone who spends more than five months in the country, then by carefully watching how long you stay in each one you could be resident in both places at once. Alternatively you could arrange to b resident in neither.

Having a 'residence' (i.e. owning a house) in a country does not necessarily make you a resident of that country. It's usually about how long you stay in the country.

Being or not being a resident of a country makes a difference to how you can travel, but mostly in small ways. As an obvious one, most countries do not allow you to 'reside' there without permission (a visa) over and above what a visitor would have, but since you are talking about countries where you are a citizen that's not an issue. Being a resident elsewhere does not prevent you from visiting a country of your citizenship (with some exceptions regarding places that don't allow dual citizenships).

Most countries have different regulations about what you can bring into the country depending on your residency. They also can have different tax and healthcare laws depending on residency, but those aren't directly related to travel.

Comment: It's also worth noting that most people try hard to *avoid* residency in multiple places simultaneously, since that can cause a lot of tax pain.  I suspect the OP is actually asking about the *right* to reside (permanent residency) in multiple countries simultaneously.

Comment: Except that his example only talks about countries he is a (theoretical) citizen of.